# Facebook Realtime Comments on photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, real-time

I am currently using the Facebook realtime updates feature in my application. I am looking for comments, on photos, status updates etc. I have successfully got it to work on a status update, on a post of a photo to a wall and a friend's post on the wall. However I can't get it to work on a photo which is within the owner's album. Neither the updated time of the album nor the photo's updated time change. I want to limit my queries as much as possible. 
What's the best way to approach this?